# Access nested State in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My state looking like this

```
this.state = { 
    potato: {
        chips: 'yum',
        fries: 'even better',
    }
}
```

Then I want to access `fries`. `wrapper.state('potato')`  get me to the first level, how to go deeper? It is not

- `wrapper.state('potato').state('fries')`
- `wrapper.state('potato', 'fries')`
- `wrapper.state(['potato', 'fries'])`
- `wrapper.state('potato').fries`
- `wrapper.state('potato')['fries']`

When I do

```
const potato = wrapper.state('potato');
```

and then

```
console.log(potato);
```

I get

```
{
     chips: 'yum',
     fries: 'even better',
}
```

However, accessing it via

```
console.log(potato.chips);
console.log(potato.fries);
console.log(potato.potato.chips)
```

all returns

> undefined

I dont get it...

Comment: actually `wrapper.state('potato').fries` and `wrapper.state('potato')['fries']` are both valid. Are you sure `this.state` is initialized when you are trying read it?

Comment: But typically I believe it's wrong way to access state in your tests anyway. Tests better to rely/check `render()`'s result rather on `state` or any internal methods. What if component is refactored and `state`'s structure is changed? Surely, tests will fail but it does not mean component is broken.

Comment: @skyboyer Certain states of the state are essential for the component to work properly. If component is refactored, the render() most likely will change too. In either way, tests need update anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is get the state at first and access the property by using dot notation.

i.e

`wrapper.state().potato.fries`

`wrapper.state('potato').fries`

You can also use bracket notation.

i.e.

`wrapper.state()['potato']['fries']`

`wrapper.state('potato')['fries']`