# Call function passed as prop in Enzym

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My Component looks like this

```
const FooBar = ({
    onClose,
}) => {
    return (
        <div
            className='foo'>
            <Icon
                name='close'

                onClick={onClose} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

My test looks the following

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();
const title = 'Title';

it('calls the onClose function', () => {
    const component = mount(
        <FooBar
            title={title}

            onClose={mockFn}
        />
    );

    component.instance().onClose();
    expect(mockFn).toBeCalled();
    component.unmount();
});
```

That returns

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'onClose' of null

How do I call the `onClose` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
component.find(Icon).first().props().onClick();
```

Also, take a look at `react-testing-library` it makes this kind of testing easier.

Comment: that gives me  `ReferenceError: Icon is not defined`

Comment: you need to import `Icon` in your test

Comment: Thats it. Any ideas regarding this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622739/access-nestes-state-in-enzym

Comment: I think generally asserting state is frowned upon, because state is meant to be internal to the component, and changes to state, such as renaming variables, should not break the test.