# How do you test object state in jest and enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test the state of a component in jest. It contains an object and I know in jest, there is a method .state(state property), but it only returns the object in my case. For example, the state would be like this

```
this.state = {
    Person: {
         name: "sample name",
         school: "sample school name"
    }
}
```

and when I do `expect(wrapper.state("Person")).toBe("name");`, it obviously fails. I tried doing `expect(wrapper.state("Person").name).toBe("name");` and that won't work. I also tried getting the result of wrapper.state and getting the name from it, but it won't let me get properties from it. How can I get properties from an object from the state.

Comment: It's not a jest issue, which is just the runner, but it depends on your testing utility.
You are probably using Enzyme... I suggest you to edit/rename your question and look at https://airbnb.io/enzyme/ in case

Comment: You should use `expect(wrapper.state("Person").name).toBe("sample name");`. May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622739/access-nestes-state-in-enzym) will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the `state` under the key `Person`, you could do:

```
expect(wrapper.state("Person")).toEqual({
     name: "sample name",
     school: "sample school name"
});
```